# Find the earliest date from an array

Tags: java, arrays

So, the array will be of the format:

```
String[][] resultsArray = new String[][] { 
        { X, Y, "2014-10-22 12:00", Z},
        { X, Y, "2014-10-24 12:00", Z},
        { X, Y, "2014-10-26 12:00", Z},
};
```

From this I need to retrieve the earliest date.

I already have a loop for another purpose that is looping through each item in the array, so I intend to reuse it. It is in the format:

```
for (int i=0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
    result += resultsArray[i][1] + "text" + resultArray[i][2];
}
```

My current thinking is to add the date value from the array into a new array (dateArray) on each iteration, then call `Arrays.sort(dateArray)` and grab `dateArray[0]`.

However, this seems pretty inefficient and clumsy, and I suspect I'm missing some simple trick.

Comment: Can you use Java 8 and Streams?

Comment: Potentially, I'd rather stick to backwards compatible methods where possible though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One (simple) solution is to assign a min value to the first element in the array, and then iterate from the second to the end comparing each value against the `min` (and because of your date format you can use lexical ordering). Something like,

```
String min = resultsArray[0][2];
for (int i=1; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
    if (resultsArray[i][2].compareTo(min) < 0) {
        min = resultsArray[i][2];
    }
}
System.out.println(min);
```

Output is

```
2014-10-22 12:00
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't think of writing a concise sort for it. Will mark as answer when available.

Comment: Additionally, thanks for introducing me to the phrase "lexical ordering". Self explanatory, but sums up the concept nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as Elliott's, specially because resultsArray is altered by the sort method, but I think it's relevant to show here an alternative

```
    String[][] resultsArray = new String[][] { 
            { "X2", "Y2", "2014-10-24 12:00", "Z2"},
            { "X1", "Y1", "2014-10-22 12:00", "Z1"},
            { "X0", "Y1", "2014-10-26 12:00", "Z0"},
    }; 
    Arrays.sort(resultsArray, new Comparator<String[]>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            return o1[2].compareTo(o2[2]);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(resultsArray[0][2]);
```